# How to show/export all visitors with visitortags from an engagement plan using Sitecore dekstop interface?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

For a project I want to show/export all visitors with visitortags from an engagement plan. The export is for creating an overview and checking purposes. It's important to show the business I have done my work correctly. I prefer a way without writing any programcode.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default in Sitecore, so you will have to write some code.

If you click the supervisor you will be able to see the USERS in a state in an engagement plan, but not VISITORS. Even though you can see the users, you won't be able to see the visitor tags, for that given user.